# Unable to connect to SMTP - "smtp.outlook.com",587 using Python2.7 from Linux server

Tags: linux, smtp, linux-networking, python

I have a small python script below which sends emails to my company outlook email. it works fine on my personal computer but when i am deploying it to server it keeps running and timeout but doesn't send email .

```
import os
import smtplib
import subprocess
from sys import exit

cmd = 'df -kh'
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
std,err = p1.communicate()
output=std.decode()
#print (output)
smtp=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 587)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.ehlo()

smtp.login('email','password')


subject = 'Send_Disk_Info_Daily'
body = output;

msg = (("subject : {} ".format(subject))+("\n\n{}".format(body)))

smtp.sendmail('email', 'email',msg)

smtp.quit()
```

Below is the error when it gets timedout-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_disk_info.py", line 16, in <module>
    smtp=smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.outlook.com', 587, timeout=20)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 789, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 315, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 794, in _get_socket
    new_socket = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

I am not able to do telnet to outlook, it also gets timed out. see below:-

```
[linux_server Python]$ telnet smtp.outlook.com 587
Trying 40.101.4.2...

^C
[linux_server Python]$
```

below are listening ports on this server.

```
linux_server Python]$ netstat -tulpn|grep -i listen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::37712                :::*                    LISTEN      45077/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      44458/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN      44458/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::32858                :::*                    LISTEN      44648/java
[linux_server Python]$
```

Can someone help me understand the issue and fix it. Or is there any alternate way to config this email sending script.
Any help is appreciated . Thanks in advance !

Comment: *Where* are you deploying it? It looks like port 587 is blocked outgoing from where you are.

Comment: @vidarlo yes, seems so. Any other alternative ways ?

Comment: Talk with the provider to see what they suggest.

Comment: @vidarlo provider means the server owner ?

Comment: yes, that's right